# my proxy server isn't visible from outside of the network

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm writing an http proxy server (homework assignment). I got it working on my home network but i can't connect to it from the outside.
I've configured the router to forward communication on the port i use to the machine running the server, turned off windows firewall and entered my outside real-world ip in the brwoser's proxy settings. Is there anything else i should do ?

UPDATE:
turns out the problem was with the address to which i was binding the server. When I used "localhost" it didn't work, once i removed it and only supplied the port, the server was bound to some default address and everything started working. What address should have i used ?

Answer (score 2):

I would hook up [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) on the WAN and LAN side of your firewall (does not have to be simultaneous).  Do you see your packets on both sides?  Does it look as expected?  Next use wireshark on the server with the proxy... same questions.

This will isolate where the problem(s) are.

Comment: I did try using wireshark for debugging. When i connect to the proxy locally (127.0.0.1) everything works fine. When i set the proxy address to my routers external ip - no packets are sent anywhere, i just get a "proxy server refusing connections" error message from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the router/firewall's rules prevent internal computers from accessing internal servers via the router/firewall's external IP-address.

To test this sort of setup, I use a separate external network connection (e.g. a laptop with a tethered 3G phone and with RJ45, Bluetooth, USB-modems and WiFi disconnected).

Answer (score 0):

turns out the problem was with the address to which i was binding the server. When I used "localhost" it didn't work, once i removed it and only supplied the port, the server was bound to some default address and everything started working